# The result is 7 game

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

**The goal** of this game is to find **the lowest score** for the 10 equations below.

> 0 `?` 0 `?` 0 `?` 0 = 7
>   1 `?` 1 `?` 1 `?` 1 = 7
>   2 `?` 2 `?` 2 `?` 2 = 7
>   3 `?` 3 `?` 3 `?` 3 = 7
>   4 `?` 4 `?` 4 `?` 4 = 7
>   5 `?` 5 `?` 5 `?` 5 = 7
>   6 `?` 6 `?` 6 `?` 6 = 7
>   7 `?` 7 `?` 7 `?` 7 = 7
>   8 `?` 8 `?` 8 `?` 8 = 7
>   9 `?` 9 `?` 9 `?` 9 = 7

**The accepted mathematical operators are:**
`+`, `−`, `×`, `÷`, `x²`, `√`, `!` ,`(` and `)`

*Note:

Implicit multiplication isn't allowed (e.g. 2(2))*
*You are allowed to put one or more of the accepted operators anywhere in the equations, but at least one operator must replace the `?`:s.*

**This is how you calculate the score:**
One point for every `+`, `−`, `×`, `÷`, `x²`, `√`, `!` ,`(` and `)`, so make the equations as short as possible.
Add together all point for the 10 equations - the lowest score wins!

***Test your formula at:***
https://www.mathway.com/Algebra

Comment: Unclear.  (1) I guess each `?` must be replaced by ***one or more*** operator(s)?  Or are you allowing things like [(ROT13) bar sbyybjrq ol bar vf ryrira](http://www.decode.org/?q=bar+sbyybjrq+ol+bar+vf+ryrira "1 followed by 1 is 11 (eleven)")?  (2) I guess we’re allowed to put `(` at the beginning and `)` at the end.  (3) Is unary minus allowed?  (4) I guess that exponentiation isn’t allowed, although it’s (IMHO) a more fundamental algebraic operator than factorial. Since you have explicitly documented one exclusion (implicit multiplication by concatenation), you should probably mention this.

Comment: Peregrine Rook, thanks alerting me on that the `x²` (opposite to `√`) was missing from the accepted operators, that was not my intention. Sorry, but great job solving it without. I also edited the Note to make it clear that '...one or more of the accepted operators could be anywhere in the equations...'

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with 10 points for 0...

> (0!+0!+0!)!+0!

...and 6 points for 1

> (1+1+1)!+1

... and 7 points for 2

> (2+2)!!-2/2

... and 3 points for 3

> 3+3+3/3

... and 3 points for 4

> 4+4-4/4

... and 5 points for 5

> 5+(5+5)/5

... and 5 points for 6 (or 6 points if double factorial is not acceptable).

> 6!!/6-6/6   or  6+√(6*6)/6

... and 5 points for 7

> 7+(7-7)*7

... and 6 points for 8

> 8-√(8*8)/8

... and 4 points for 9 (thanks to Jaap Scherphuis)

> 9-√9+9/9

So total points is 54 points. I haven't found a way to do it without the [double factorial](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/double-factorial) for 2.

Comment: For $6$ and $8$ you can also remove a set of brackets if you extend the square root over the top.

Comment: Penguino, your solution for 8 is great and Jaap, I like your solution for 9.

Comment: Ironically, 2 ``?`` 2 ``?`` 2 ``?`` 2 ``?`` 2 = 7 is easier  than 2 ``?`` 2 ``?`` 2 ``?`` 2 = 7.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis wait, so it wasn't even the radical in the first place that undermined the solution xD Thanks for that pick-up! I can be dumb sometimes...

Comment: @Penguino Why didn't you use my suggestion for $6$ and $8$? I.e. use $\sqrt{6*6}$ to eliminate a pair of brackets.

Comment: I feel that extending the square root sign is not in the spirit of the problem. The same logic would let you extend a division sign to make a fraction where the numerator and/or denominator was a sum. That would let you express (a+b)/(c+d) with only 3 symbols, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Penguino: We can use MathJax in comments, so you can say ``$a+b \over c+d$`` and get $a+b \over c+d$.

Comment: The link the OP gives for testing your formula allows it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I’m misunderstanding yesterday’s edit to the question,
but I believe that I can get the score for `2` down to 4 points:

> $2^2+2+2/2$

> My understanding of the edit to the question is that,
> in the *`N`* equation,
> we can use `N2` as an operator,
> and that this counts as only one (not two) of the four uses of *`N`*,
> even if *`N`* is `2`.